# iOS - Modally Present VC with blur over previous View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm attempting to present a VC modally that shows a blur of the previous view controller. This is my attempt. The problem is that this only works maybe 50% of the time. Half of the time the blur works as intended, the other half I only get the grey blur as if the background is black (no background content).

```
-(void)plusButtonPressedOnCell:(SASearchTableViewCell *)cell
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ActionMenu" bundle:nil];
    SAActionMenuViewController *actionMenuVC = (SAActionMenuViewController *)[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:actionMenuVC animated:NO completion:^{
        //animations
    }];
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: How do you create the blur effect? maybe it draws the blur before has proper size (layoutSubviews is called)?

Comment: I know it's not exactly what you're asking for, but this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18661) might help you

Comment: Thanks, the blur was fine, It was the way I was my presentation style that was incorrect though. @ps4

Answer (score 1):

My presentation style was incorrect, and I was attempting it on the wrong view controller. This was the fix.

This line:

```
 self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

needed to be:

```
  actionMenuVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
```